# C++ Passing std::string into Pointer-to-C-String Parameter

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm using a function from SDL, and one of the parameters is of type `const GLchar* const*`, so in order to call it, I would need to pass in a reference of a C-string like this:

```
const char *str = "test";
glShaderSource(... , &str, ...);
```

However, I have an `std::string` that I want to pass in, and doing something like this gives an error:

```
std::string str = "test";
glShaderSource(... , &str.c_str(), ...);
```

I know that I can simply make a new `const char*` variable and save the `std::string` to it like this:

```
const char *cstr = str.c_str();
```

But is there any way around this? I don't like having to make a new variable. I tried using a lambda but that didn't work.

Comment: Oops, it's a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way around it.

The function `glShaderSource` needs a pointer to a pointer to a character buffer (because it wants you to pass one *or more* C-strings), and you can't take the address of an rvalue (which is what the expression `str.c_str()` is).

But that's not really a problem, since in your final example all you're doing is assigning a pointer to a pointer. This is extremely cheap and easy.

Don't be afraid of "making a new variable" — naming things is good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is: why does the function need a pointer-to-a-pointer? In a lot of cases with c-style functions, they provide this kind of interface because they want to modify the target pointer to point to something else (such as something created internally by the function). If that is the case, then assigning the result of `string::c_str()` to a variable and then passing it in is kind of pointless, as it would be re-assigned to point to something else anyway.

I recommend you check the documentation of this function more thoroughly to ensure this is not the case (which it probably is).

Comment: From the question: _"one of the parameters is of type `const GLchar* const*`"_. If you look up the function, you'll see that it's because it expects an _array_ of pointers-to-strings.

Comment: That is, if _you'd_ checked the documentation then you'd have seen that this answer does not address the question at all. :)

Comment: But hang on a second here @LightnessRacesinOrbit. After your comment I *did* check the documentation and it shows that I'm exactly right. The parameter *is* in fact an output parameter just as I suspected (see [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderSource.xhtml)). What is the problem with my answer?

Comment: Excuse me but which part of that documentation says that this is an output parameter?

Comment: The bit of it that is in my imagination, it seems.

Comment: Finally, we are in agreement. :)